# Prove that the linear map of the basis $V$ is a spanning set of the image of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

> Suppose that $f:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map of finite-dimensional vector spaces and that $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. Prove that $\{f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_n)$} is a spanning set for $im(f)$. Also suppose that $\{v_1,v_2,...v_k\}$ (the first $k$ vectors of $S$) is a basis for $ker(f)$ (so in particular $k=nullity(f)$). Prove that $\{f(v_{k+1}),f(v_{k+2}),...f(v_n)\}$ is a basis for $im(f)$.

Not sure if the proof for the first part I have done is good.

$span(S)=V\Rightarrow \alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_nv_n=w,\forall w\in V $

$\Rightarrow \alpha_1f(v_1)+\alpha_2f(v_2)+...\alpha_nf(v_n)=f(w), \forall f(w)\in im(f).$ By the fact that $f$ is a linear map. Therefore this implies that $f(v_i), i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ is a spanning set of $im(f)$.

For the second part, it is obvious from $$dim(V)=rank+nullity$$ That we have $n-k$ vectors which is the $dim(im(f))$. Therefore we just have to prove linear independence. For this we need $f$ to be injective to be sure that $f(v)=0\Rightarrow v=0$, which means the $nullity(f)=0$, which is where I get stuck.

Comment: You don't need $f$ to be injective (at least on $V$) - it isn't in general. If $f(v)=0$ then $v\in\ker{V}$, so $v$ is in the span of $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}$...

Comment: You know that $f(v_{k+1},\ldots$ are a spanning set, hence it *contains* a basis. But by looking at the dimension it cannot *properly* contain a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a_{k+1}f(v_{k+1}) \ +\ a_{k+2}f(v_{k+2})\ +...+\ a_nf(v_n)$ = $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...+a_nv_v)=0$ $\Rightarrow$  $a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...+a_nv_n\in Ker\ (f)$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...a_nv_n=b_1v_1+...b_kv_k$ (Why ?) $\Rightarrow$ $(-b_1v_1)+(-b_2v_2)+...+(-b_kv_k)+a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...+a_nv_n=0$. Now $\{v_1,..,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ so can you conclude that $a_{k+1}=a_{k+2}=...=a_n=0$ ?